# Install Anaconda Navigator on Ubuntu 22.04 Raspberry Pi 4B with 8 GB RAM , Error: "Your operating system appears not to be 64-bit"

Tags: 22.04, 64-bit, raspberrypi, anaconda

Im trying to install the anaconda navigator on my raspberry pi with ubuntu 22.04.

When i follow the tutorial, you need to use „Anaconda3-2022.10-Linux-x86_64.sh“ (latest Version). After downloading it, i want to install it with „bash Anaconda3-2022.10-Linux-x86_64.sh„.

I always get the same error straight away.

„WARNING: Your operating system appears not to be 64-bit, but you are trying to install a 64-bit version of Anaconda“

I never saw that in any tutorial so im quiet confused what to do. I would be very happy if someone could help me.

Comment: A pi 4B would require **ARM**64 (aarch64) not **AMD**64 (x86_64) I think?

Comment: When I try to install ARM64, I don't get that Warning mentioned above, but another error: Anaconda3-22.10-Linux-aarch64.sh : Line 408: 2131 Illegal instruction (core dumped) "$CONDA_EXEC" constructor: "$PREFIX" --extract-conda-pkgs

Comment: It looks like that installer may be for the AWS Graviton specifically

Comment: Thanks in advance for the answers. Do you know if there's another way to install the navigator on my raspberry pi ?